# Populate different sections of tableview from single Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I am new to iOS development & just having problem to populate data in different sections from single dictionary.here is my dictionary

```
var menuItems = [["city":"Lahore","cityimage":"2","country":"Pakistan"],["city":"istanbul","cityimage":"3","country":"Turkey"],["city":"Moscow","cityimage":"4","country":"Russia"],["city":"Riyadh","cityimage":"5","country":"KSA"]]
```

here is my function this works fine for a single section with multiple rows the problem is I don't know how to use index path.section in this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for:indexPath) as! TableCellTry
    cell.lblCityName.text!=menuItems[indexPath.row]["city"]!
    cell.lblProvince.text!=menuItems[indexPath.row]["country"]!
    cell.imgCity.image=UIImage(named:menuItems[indexPath.row]["cityimage"]!)
}
```

Comment: Which elements are supposed to be in section #0 and which in section #1?

Comment: first 2 cities in section #0 & last 2 in section #1

Comment: Then @Michael's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219619/6536841) is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the elements that should be in the same section in array like this

```
var menuItems = [
            [
                ["city":"Lahore","cityimage":"2","country":"Pakistan"],
                ["city":"istanbul","cityimage":"3","country":"Turkey"]
            ],
            [
                ["city":"Moscow","cityimage":"4","country":"Russia"],
                ["city":"Riyadh","cityimage":"5","country":"KSA"]
            ]
        ]
```

you can access them with

```
cell.lblCityName.text!=menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]["city"]!
```